# Spring Social Facebook access token

Tags: java, spring, facebook, spring-mvc

I tried to integrate Spring Social on one of my Spring MVC projects and I followed the steps described in this [blog](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/adding-social-sign-in-to-a-spring-mvc-web-application-registration-and-login/) ans I also used as reference the Spring Projects found on [Github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-samples), but I was confused on this set of codes found on the github projects.

```
@Bean
@Scope(value = "request",proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
public Facebook facebook(ConnectionRepository connectionRepository){
    Connection<Facebook> connection = connectionRepository.findPrimaryConnection(Facebook.class);
    return connection != null ? connection.getApi() : new FacebookTemplate();
}
```

The primary connection for facebook cannot be found even though the user clicks the "Sign In Using Facebook" button and thus it returns a new instance of FacebookTemplate and when I try use it I always get an access deined because I don't have any authentication/access token. Are there any solution to get the token key?

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: @The1Fitz here is the error "org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.social.MissingAuthorizationException: Authorization is required for the operation, but the API binding was created without authorization."